# Angularjs POST URL data to PHP and print the response

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have written the code but not getting output. How can I print the output on the page using AngularJS?

When I am using the dynamic URL, the active link color change isn't working.

```
// Grab path parameters and query parameters
var routeParameters = $routeParams;
$scope.pageParameter = (routeParameters["pageParam"] || "No page parameter");
$scope.queryParameter = (routeParameters["queryParam"] || "No query parameter");

// Do an $http call to your site
$http({
    url: "http://keralapsctuts.com/app/index.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        param1: $scope.pageParameter,
        param2: $scope.queryParameter
    }
}).success(function(response) {
    $scope.values = reponse;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `response` object represents your HTTP response coming back. I think you should only be assigning the data to you scope values property. So update it like so:

```
.success(function(response){
    $scope.values = reponse.data;
    console.log($scope.values); // print to console.
});
```

If you want to display in the view, @tokkov show how in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to reference the values variable within your page template.  So something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="value in values">
A: {{value.a}} B: {{value.b}}
</div>
```

Obviously the specifics would depend on what the response data looks like and how you want to display it.